# Not able to understand html and css, coordinate entry form

Tags: php, html, css

I had gone through w3school and read some online resource it's really difficult for me to understand html and css, please someone help me, I am beginner

I have created this form but problem is its not coming center and not looking nice, I want to see like this

```
                                  Latitude Max

                                    [    ]
      Longitude Min [   ]                         [    ] Longitude Max

                                    [    ]

                                  Latitude Min

                                     SUBMIT
```

Many people told me to use dreamviewer its gui based, but I am using centos so I like to understand and write html and css code manually.

See here is my code

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <body>
           <form action="search.php" method="post">
           Latitude Max <input  type="lat_max" name="RANGE[]"></br/>
               </br/>Longitude Min <input  type="lon_min" name="RANGE[]">
               <input type="lon_max" name="RANGE[]">Longitude Max</br/>
               </br/>Latitude Min <input type="lat_min" name="RANGE[]">
               </br/><input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
           </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

and this form I want to call inside php script please help me.. as I beginner I am taking more than 1 day to design one html page, hard but true.

Comment: When you're a beginner, it takes time. Also, try other sources as well. w3school isn't the greatest of sources.

Comment: _“as I beginner I am taking more than 1 day to design one html page”_ – so what? That’s how you _learn_, after all. So do some (more) research on how to layout with CSS, and what structure could help in achieving the desired layout. If we were to just present you with a solution, then were would be the learning effect for you :-)

Comment: I am trying this from last 4 hours, so posted, thank you.

Comment: To start with, note that your text describing each input is not 'contained' within an element. You need to do that so you can then 'tell' that element where to position itself via CSS. I'd suggest putting said text into `<label>` objects, as that is contextually appropriate (as well as accessible).

Comment: And don't use DreamWeaver. That will only make things more confusing for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm infinitely sympathetic to beginners, since I was one about a year ago. It takes time, and reading tons of code. I'll give you a "solution", but spend most of the time going over the CSS portion of the fiddle. If this is your first step, you still have much to learn about reading the values from the input fields, cleaning them up, and using them.

A large program begins with a single [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/SL7GZ/).

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.singleinput {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.doubleinput {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.minlong {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.maxlong {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.buttondiv {
    width: 80px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
input {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Suggestions:

1. Learn how to use jsfiddle - you can experiment for hour after hour without have to upload your files to a server. It has all the 'stuff' (jQuery) built in.
2. Read about div widths, and "floating" divs.
3. The "overflow: hidden" is a trick for floating divs within divs. You just have to memorize it.
4. Play with the margins and watch what happens.
5. Figure out was "margin: 0px auto;" means.
6. Best of luck! Do NOT give up!

Comment: Quite different from my solution, but looking good as well. +1

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a good idea to make actual labels for the input. Both for property HTML and for convenient styling. Also, it's handy to embed the separate chunks in divs:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
       <form action="search.php" method="post">
           <div class="pos lat_max">
             <label for="lat_max">Latitude Max</label>
             <input id="lat_max" name="RANGE[]"/>
           </div>

           <div class="pos lon_min">
             <label for="lon_min">Longitude Min</label>
             <input id="lon_min" name="RANGE[]"/>
           </div>

           <div class="pos lon_max">
             <label for="lon_max">Longitude Max</label>
             <input id="lon_max" name="RANGE[]"/>
           </div>

           <div class="pos lat_min">
             <label for="lat_min">Latitude Min</label>
             <input id="lat_min" name="RANGE[]"/>
           </div>

           <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
       </form>

</body>
</html>
```

After that you can style them:

```
/* Start by absolutely positioning every element so you can put them 
   where ever you want. This is not always the right thing to do, but I think
   it is for pieces of the website where you have a very specific positioning 
   like this. */
div.pos {
    width: 10rem;
    position: absolute;
}
label {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.pos label,
.pos input {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Center the container of the latitude inputs */
.lat_max,
.lat_min {
    left: 50%;
    right: auto;
}

/* Correct the position, because the left side of the container is centered */
.lat_max *,
.lat_min * {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
/* Lat-min at the bottom */
.lat_min {
    bottom: 0;
}

/* lon in the vertical middle of the page */
.lon_min,
.lon_max {
    top: 50%;
}

/* lon max on the right */
.lon_max {
    right: 0;
}
```

I know, this is not exactly what you described, but you can continue finetuning it.
http://jsfiddle.net/s99hU/

One important note: 
`position: absolute` now works within the page, but actually it looks at the closest parent that has `position: absolute` or `position: relative`.

`position: relative` doesn't move the element itself, so you can add that to the form. This will postion the inputs in the form, rather than spread over the page. After that, you can give the form an exact width and height (especially the height is needed, otherwise the form will collapse). The inputs will then be positioned inside the form, and the form itself is a self contained block, a building stone that can be embedded and positioned inside the page however you want.

Comment: +1 thank you so much why submit button is not coming down ? and its taking full page

Comment: It is taking the full page now, but I described how you can make it obey a container. The button is moved in this update: http://jsfiddle.net/s99hU/1/  The advantage of this method, is that every item is positioned separately, so you have a very fine grained control over each element. Because elements are positioned in an absolute sense, they are taken out of the flow of the page. That's why the button was at the top: It was the first and only element in the regular flow inside the form..

Comment: Very nice. I've not seen the 'left:50%' and 'right: auto' before. I'll play with that a bit.

Comment: The `right: auto` is obsolete. I've accidentally left that in.